# Query MySQL with LIMIT 2 with case

Tags: php, mysql

I want to query ORDER BY DESC with LIMIT 2

```
$q = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM tb ORDER BY date_post DESC LIMIT 2");
while($d = mysqli_fetch_array($q))
{
?>
<td><?php echo $d['message'];</td>
<?php
}
```

Example data show will be :

```
<td>Hi I'm last row</td>
<td>Hi I'm second row</td>
```

I want to query ORDER BY DESC with LIMIT 2, after that I want the query show like this :

```
<td>Hi I'm second row</td>
<td>Hi I'm last row</td>
```

Any idea?

Comment: Try ORDER BY name ASC

Comment: If tried ORDER BY ASC, it will show the first data. What I want is, query last 2 data and then show last row data in second row in table like my example

Comment: It's unclear if something is not working right for you. Are you receiving errors? Is the data not coming in the order you expect?

Comment: how many rows you have in your table?

Comment: Actually the query is OK, but now I want to display last 2 data and then show last row data in second row in table like my example

Comment: @Robin assuming I have more than 10 data.

Comment: So what isn't working?

Comment: Anyway thanks for your answer @Robin. Now it worked as I wanted. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change $q

```
$q = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM 
                      (SELECT * FROM tb ORDER BY date_post DESC LIMIT 2) 
                  AS new_tb ORDER BY date_post ASC");
```

Comment: Nice.. It worked as I wanted. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that using nested query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    (SELECT * FROM tb ORDER BY date_post DESC LIMIT 2) AS `t1` 
ORDER BY date_post
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi Try the following :

```
$q = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM tb ORDER BY date_post DESC LIMIT 2");
$arr_length = count($q);
for($i=$arr_length-1;$i>=0;$i--)
{
   echo "<td>".$q[$i]['message']."</td>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ORDER BY name ASC should give you the opposite result. It might be better to sort on an id though, if you're always looking to get the last of the 2 rows.